# Which short sale number is true in OTCBB or FINRA?

Tags: shorting-securities

FINRA provide everyday's short sale data at the website:

[short sale data](https://www.finra.org/finra-data/browse-catalog/short-sale-volume-data/daily-short-sale-volume-files)

We can get field defination here [field defination](https://www.finra.org/sites/default/files/2021-07/DailyShortSaleVolumeFileLayout.pdf),  Short Volume--Aggregate reported share volume of executed short sale and short sale exempt trades during regular trading hours.
Let us select a company listing in OTCBB market--`FNMA`,download the table from the webpage    [short sale data of FNMA on 20231229](https://cdn.finra.org/equity/regsho/daily/FORFshvol20231229.txt),open it with EXCEL.

[image]

Now open [FNMA's data on OTCBB's official website](https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/FNMA/quote#level-2),we get an other data

```
DATE        SHORT INTEREST
12/29/2023   3,465,786
```

Which number is true for `short interest`?

```
3,465,786 in OTCBB or 3179805 in FINRA
```

[image]